# save smtp sent mail in outlook sent folder using outlook add in

Tags: outlook, vsto, sendmail, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I would like to send smtp send mail from outlook-addin that mail save into outlook sent folder

Note: Save mail item in sent folder from address must be which i specified smtp from address not outlook login username.

```
public bool SendEMail()
{ 
   MailMessage mailNew = new MailMessage();

   var smtp = new SmtpClient("SmtpServer")
   {
        EnableSsl = false,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
   };

    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = 
         new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "password");
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
    smtp.Credentials = credentials;
    MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("clark@gmail.com");
    mailNew.From = mailFrom;
    mailNew.To.Add("someone@gmail.com");
    mailNew.Subject = Subject;
    mailNew.IsBodyHtml = Html;
    mailNew.Body = Body;
    smtp.Send(mailNew);

    return true;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a sent item in the Sent Items folder and set all the relevant properties using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor`. Note that `PropertyAccessor` will not let you set some sender related properties. In Outlook 2010 or higher you can set the `MailItem.Sender` property.

Also note that the sent flag cannot be changed after the message is saved, so to create a sent item using OOM, you will need to create a post item, then change its `MessageClass` property to `"IPM.Note"`.

Also note that `ReceivedTime` and `SentOn` properties are reset by OOM every time the message is saved.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), you can do something like the following (off the top of my head):

```
Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
Redemption.RDOMail message = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items.Add("IPM.Note");
message.Sent = true;
message.Subject = "test";
message.Body = "fake sent message";
message.Recipients.AddEx("The Recipient", "recipient@domain.com", "SMTP", olTo);
string senderEntryID = session.AddressBook.CreateOneOffEntryID("Some Name", "SMTP", "user@domain.com", false, true);
addressEntry = session.AddressBook.GetAddressEntryFromID(senderEntryID);
message.Sender = addressEntry;
message.SentOnBehalfOf = addressEntry;
message.Save();
```